# Implicit values of generic types for implicit parameters in scala

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

I have a method:

```
def pollAll[T, O](orchestrators :Seq[O], poll :(O)=>Future[T])
                 (implicit reduce: (T, T) => T) :Future[T] =
(Future sequence orchestrators.map(poll(_))).map(res => res.reduce(reduce))
```

Now, let's assume that I have a poll  which returns `Future[Seq[A]]`. Is it at all possible to provide a generic implicit value for `reduce` parameter which concatenates any two sequences with common element type? Something like this:

```
implicit def reduceSeq[T] = (s1 :Seq[T], s2 :Seq[T]) => s1 ++ s2
```

The above doesn't work, because implicit methods are used for implicit convertions, and their results are not considered during lookup for implicit parameters.

Comment: What if T is not a Seq? Do not you miss a type bound on T?

Comment: well, of course if T in pollAll is not a Seq, there would be no value for implicit parameter, unless I'd define a specific one.

Comment: the method call "pollAll(List.empty[Int], (i:Int) => future(Seq(i)))" with your implicit declaration compiles without any errors for me. Am I missing something here?

Comment: if I try to run `pollAll(orchestrators, poll)` (where orchestrators :Seq[Orchestrator]`, the compiler complains that no implicit value for reduce parameter is found. This is correct, because implicit methods serve only for implicit conversions, and not as providers for default parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your solution either, but [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) defines types called `Semigroup` and `Monoid` which could help you here. It also includes `Semigroup` definitions for many common types like [List](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/List.scala#L103-L106) and [Int](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/AnyVal.scala#L234-L237). `SemiGroup` defines an [append](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Semigroup.scala#L22) operation. `Monoid` extends `Semigroup` but additionally provides a [`zero`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monoid.scala#L23) or an initial value. This would be useful if `orchestrators` could be empty, in which case you would want to `foldLeft` instead of `reduce`.

Note: I reversed your type parameters

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def pollAll[O, T : Semigroup](orchestrators :Seq[O], poll :(O)=>Future[T]) :Future[T] = 
 (Future sequence orchestrators.map(poll(_)))
   .map(res => res.reduce(implicitly[Semigroup[T]].append(_, _)))
```

or sugared a bit

```
def pollAll2[O, T : Semigroup](orchestrators :Seq[O], poll :(O)=>Future[T]) :Future[T] = 
 (Future traverse orchestrators)(poll(_)).map(_.reduce(_ |+| _))
```

output

```
scala> pollAll(List(1, 2, 3, 4), (i: Int) => Future.successful(i)).foreach(println)

scala> 10

scala> pollAll2(List(1, 2, 3, 4), (i: Int) => Future.successful(i)).foreach(println)

scala> 10
```